# Incorrect MAC error while using ssh from windows to linux

Tags: linux, ssh, azure, azure-virtual-desktop

I am trying to ssh from a windows system to an azure centos vm. But I am getting error incorrect MAC ... On further checking i identified it only happens when the mac algorithm used is umac-128-etm@openssh.com and there is no issue connecting if I try to specify other algorithms. Moreover i can connect to the vm from other linux machines and i can conect to other linux machines from my windows system. So i guess this has something to do with the versions of the linux and windows openssh So I tried to remove this mac algorithm from sshd_config file in my azure vm using root access and the connection succeeded for the time being but after some time the mac algorith got added back to the sshd_config file automatically. I am not the one who deployed the vm and cant redeploy it, is there any method to change this configuration and make sure it doesnt automatically get reset?

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.